# Handle empty lines in draft-js HTML format

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, html-react-parser

I am using draft-js with react. I save the content from the editor in HTML format and display the content to the user. I use [draft-convert](https://github.com/HubSpot/draft-convert) for the HTML translations.

Empty lines in the editor are saved as empty `<p></p>` blocks. Such blocks are not rendered as empty lines in the browser. For example, in react, I use [html-react-parser](https://github.com/remarkablemark/html-react-parser) to display the editor content where the empty `<p></p>` tags don't render as an empty line.

**Editor content:**

Hello

World

**HTML content:**

`<p>Hello</p><p></p><p>World</p>`

How do I make sure that the empty `<p></p>` tag is rendered as an empty line?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (block.type === 'PARAGRAPH') {
        if (!block.text) return <br />;
        return <p  />;
      }
```

Comment: Hi @Sudhansu Joshi, welcome to Stack Overflow! You may improve your answer by explaining where to put this code.